# cell format/data validation/vba to ensure the correct entry in a cell

Tags: excel, validation, vbscript

We have an invoice # format the is very strict and must match a certain format. We do this manually and I often get multiple variations so was trying to create data validation to control the entry of the invoice number.

Here’s the format:

YYYYMMDD-RNN

1. The invoice number is exactly 12 characters long
2. The first 4 characters are the year (full year, like 2018)
3. The next 2 characters are the month (like 02, must have the leading zero for 1 to 9) and not allow higher that 12.
4. The next 2 characters are the day (like 08, must have the leading zero for 1 to 9) and not allow higher that 31.
5. The next character is a “-“
6. The next character is a region identifier. Allowable numbers are 0 to 9.
7. The final 2 characters are sequential #’s beginning with 01. Must have the leading zero for 1 to 9.

Need a formula to validate this.

Comment: Have you done **anything** at all towards a solution besides draft up a list of requirements?

Comment: I was able to validate length using LEN(A1)=12; I was able to validate 201 using =EXACT(LEFT(A1,3),"201"); I was able to validate hyphen using MID(A1,9,1)="-"; I was able to validate last two number using =AND(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,11,1)),ISNUMBER(--MID(A1,12,1)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula should work, but I couldn't insert it on custom data validation. I suspect there's a character limit. If anyone could shed a light, it would be nice.

=IF(AND(LEFT(A1;4)*1<=YEAR(TODAY());LEFT(A1;4)*1>=2000);IF(AND(MID(A1;5;2)*1>=1;MID(A1;5;2)*1<=12);IF(AND(MID(A1;7;2)*1>=1;MID(A1;5;2)*1<=30);IF(MID(A1;9;1)="-";IF(AND(MID(A1;10;1)*1>=0;MID(A1;10;1)*1<=9);IF(AND(MID(A1;11;2)*1>=1;MID(A1;11;2)*1<=99);TRUE;FALSE);FALSE);FALSE);FALSE);FALSE);FALSE)

P.S.: I assumed no invoices after the year 2000.

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!!!!!!!! This worked. Custom Data Validation does have a character limit. I used the formula you gave in another cell next to the invoice # and used this formula =AND(B1)=TRUE in custom data validation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this UDF in a standard module code sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Function invoiceCheck(rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim tmp As String

    tmp = rng.Value2

    'check length
    If Len(tmp) <> 12 Then Exit Function

    'check valid date
    If Not IsDate(Join(Array(Mid(tmp, 5, 2), Mid(tmp, 7, 2), Left(tmp, 4)), "/")) Then Exit Function

    'check date is today or earlier
    If CDate(Join(Array(Mid(tmp, 5, 2), Mid(tmp, 7, 2), Left(tmp, 4)), "/")) > Date Then Exit Function

    'make sure there is a hyphen
    tmp = Split(tmp, "-")(1)

    invoiceCheck = IsNumeric(tmp)
End Function
```